# Не отсылается письмо, если не прикреплены файлы

Tags: php, файлы, input, fileupload

Невозможно отослать письмо с сайта, если пользователь не приложил к письму два файла, хотя они не являются обязательными. Но тем не менее, без их добавления отослать письмо невозможно.

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать отправку приложенных файлов не обязательным условием отправления письма.`

```
<input name="logo" type="file" />`
<input name="guide" type="file" />

<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='6; url=https://site.com'>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name']; if ($name == '') {unset($name);}}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email']; if ($email == '') {unset($email);}}
if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone']; if ($phone == '') {unset($phone);}}
if (isset($_POST['country'])) {$country = $_POST['country']; if ($country == '') {unset($country);}}
if (isset($_POST['paddress'])) {$paddress = $_POST['paddress']; if ($paddress == '') {unset($paddress);}}
if (isset($_POST['you'])) {$you = $_POST['you']; if ($you == '') {unset($you);}}
if (isset($_POST['budget'])) {$budget = $_POST['budget']; if ($budget == '') {unset($budget);}}
if (isset($_POST['background'])) {$background = $_POST['background']; if ($background == '') {unset($background);}}
if (isset($_POST['why'])) {$why = $_POST['why']; if ($why == '') {unset($why);}}
if (isset($_POST['competitors'])) {$competitors = $_POST['competitors']; if ($competitors == '') {unset($competitors);}}
if (isset($_POST['audience'])) {$audience = $_POST['audience']; if ($audience == '') {unset($audience);}}
if (isset($_POST['like'])) {$like = $_POST['like']; if ($like == '') {unset($like);}}
if (isset($_POST['dislike'])) {$dislike = $_POST['dislike']; if ($dislike == '') {unset($dislike);}}
if (isset($_POST['examples'])) {$examples = $_POST['examples']; if ($examples == '') {unset($examples);}}
if (isset($_POST['style'])) {$style = $_POST['style']; if ($style == '') {unset($style);}}
if (isset($_POST['words'])) {$words = $_POST['words']; if ($words == '') {unset($words);}}
if (isset($_POST['colors'])) {$colors = $_POST['colors']; if ($colors == '') {unset($colors);}}
if (isset($_POST['language'])) {$language = $_POST['language']; if ($language == '') {unset($language);}}
if (isset($_FILES['logo'])) {$logo = $_FILES['logo']; if ($logo == '') {unset($logo);}}
if (isset($_FILES['guide'])) {$guide = $_FILES['guide']; if ($guide == '') {unset($guide);}}
if (isset($_POST['features'])) { $features = !empty($_POST['features']) ? '"' . implode('", "', $_POST['features']) . '"' : ''; if ($features == '') { unset($features); } }
if (isset($_POST['sideortop'])) {$sideortop = $_POST['sideortop']; if ($sideortop == '') {unset($sideortop);}}
if (isset($_POST['sections'])) {$sections = $_POST['sections']; if ($sections == '') {unset($sections);}}
if (isset($_POST['updating'])) {$updating = $_POST['updating']; if ($updating == '') {unset($updating);}}
if (isset($_POST['skills'])) {$skills = $_POST['skills']; if ($skills == '') {unset($skills);}}
if (isset($_POST['other'])) {$other = $_POST['other']; if ($other == '') {unset($other);}}

if (isset($logo)){                                                                   

$file_attached1 = false;
$file_attached2 = false;

if(isset($logo)) //check uploaded file
    {
        //get file details we need
        $file_tmp_name1       = $logo['tmp_name'];
        $file_name1           = $logo['name'];
        $file_size1           = $logo['size'];
        $file_type1           = $logo['type'];
        $file_error1      = $logo['error'];

        //exit script and output error if we encounter any
        if($file_error1>0)
        {
            $mymsg = array(
            1=>"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini",
            2=>"The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form",
            3=>"The uploaded file was only partially uploaded",
            4=>"No file was uploaded",
            6=>"Missing a temporary folder" );

            $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => $mymsg[$file_error1]));
            die($output);
        }

        //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
        $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name1, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size1);
        fclose($handle);
        $encoded_content1 = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        //now we know we have the file for attachment, set $file_attached to true
        $file_attached1 = true;
    }

    if(isset($guide)) //check uploaded file
    {
        //get file details we need
        $file_tmp_name2   = $guide['tmp_name'];
        $file_name2           = $guide['name'];
        $file_size2           = $guide['size'];
        $file_type2           = $guide['type'];
        $file_error2      = $guide['error'];

        //exit script and output error if we encounter any
        if($file_error2>0)
        {
            $mymsg = array(
            1=>"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini",
            2=>"The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form",
            3=>"The uploaded file was only partially uploaded",
            4=>"No file was uploaded",
            6=>"Missing a temporary folder" );

            $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => $mymsg[$file_error2]));
            die($output);
        }

        //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
        $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name2, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size2);
        fclose($handle);
        $encoded_content2 = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        //now we know we have the file for attachment, set $file_attached to true
        $file_attached2 = true;
    }



$address = "admin@site.com";
$sub = "Brief";

$mes = "Client Name: $name \nE-mail: $email \nPhone: $phone \nCountry: $country \nPostal Address: $paddress \nClient is: $you \nProject Budget: $budget \nBackground information: $background \nWhy do you need a website?: $why \nWho are your competitors?: $competitors \nWho is your target audience?: $audience \nWhat do you like about websites?: $like \nWhat do you dislike about websites?: $dislike \nProvide examples of websites (or parts of websites) you like the design and functionality.: $examples \nWhat Style would you prefer for your website?: $style \nAre there any other words you would like to use to describe the required look?: $words \nDo you have any colours in mind for your website?: $colors \nHow many language versions should your future website have?: $language \nPlease upload your logo if you have it.: $logo \nIs there an official corporate style guide I need to follow? Please upload PDF version.: $guide \nWhat features would you like on your website?: $features \nWould you prefer side or top level navigation?: $sideortop \nInsert the sections that should be present on your website. E.g. Home page, News, About us, Product catalogue, FAQ, Contact etc.: $sections \nWho will be updating and promoting your website?: $updating \nWhat level of computer and internet skills do they have?: $skills \nOther Comments?: $other";

if($file_attached1 or $file_attached2) //continue if we have the file
    {
        $boundary = md5("sanwebe");

        //header
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "From:".$email."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email."" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n";

        //plain text
        $body = $mes;
        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
        $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($mes));
        if ($file_attached1 ) {
                //attachment
            $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
            $body .="Content-Type: $file_type1; name=\"$file_name1\"\r\n";
            $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name1\"\r\n";
            $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
            $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n";
            $body .= $encoded_content1;
        }
        if ($file_attached2 ) {
                //attachment
            $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
            $body .="Content-Type: $file_type2; name=\"$file_name2\"\r\n";
            $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name2\"\r\n";
            $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
            $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n";
            $body .= $encoded_content2;
        }
}   

$send = mail($address, $sub, $body, $headers);
if ($send == 'true')
{echo "The brief has been sent. I will reply by email as soon as possible. Talk to you soon, Admin";}
else {echo "Oops, There was a problem sending the brief.";}


}
else
{
echo '<pre>' . print_r(get_defined_vars(), true) . '</pre>';
echo "Please, fill out all required fields";
}
?>
```

Comment: `if($file_attached1 or $file_attached2) //continue if we have the file`

Comment: @Visman удаление этой строки не помогает. Выдаёт: {"type":"error","text":"No file was uploaded"}

Comment: А ее не надо удалять. Это условие, которое проверяет наличие хотя бы одного файла.

Comment: @Visman спасибо. как это условие тогда исправить, если не удалять его?

Answer (score 0):

> как это условие тогда исправить, если не удалять его?

Допишите вариант для не верного условия. Примерно так:

```
if($file_attached1 or $file_attached2) //continue if we have the file
{
    ....
} 
else 
{
    //header
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "From:".$email."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email. "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8";

    //plain text
    $body = $mes;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. дописал, но эффекта нет: "type":"error","text":"No file was uploaded"                                                                              if($file_attached1 or $file_attached2) //continue if we have the file
 {
  $boundary = md5("sanwebe");

  //header

....

   $body .= $encoded_content2;
  }
}   

else 
{
    //header
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "From:".$email."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email. "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8";

    //plain text
    $body = $mes;
}